i want create online editor but not working
   // C# snippets
                    { caption: "Console.WriteLine", value: "Console.WriteLine(${1:\"message\"});", meta: "C#" },
                    { caption: "if", value: "if (${1:condition}) {\n\t${2:// body}\n}", meta: "C#" },
                    { caption: "for", value: "for (int ${1:i} = 0; ${1:i} < ${2:n}; ${1:i}++) {\n\t${3:// body}\n}", meta: "C#" },

this code given me a chatgpt but it's doesn't work correctly, i want when user typing any command of c# language then automatically that text take a appropriate color like a visual studio or vs code
